# How to test methods which using private parameters without getters/setters(Injected)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

In Java like this:

```
@Injected
private Int a;

@Injected
private Int b;

public void myMethod() {
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

I have no idea how to test this method.

Comment: What you ask is unclear. Are you asking how to test some System.out.println? or how to set/get the fields a, b?

Comment: could you use constructor injection instead of field injection?

Comment: @RC. how to set/get the fields a, b

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski i can't

Comment: use a cdi container to write some integration test by arquillian, e.g: weld.

Comment: Could you provide an example of usage? I.e. for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend you to write code like this and if it is already written to refactor it. The idea of dependency injection is to have dependencies which can be injected runtime. At the moment they are injected by reflection so as davidxx says you have to use reflection to set values which you need . This may cause you a lot of headaches.
Instead of using field injection like this :

```
@Inject
private Int b;
```

You can use setter injection like this :

```
@Inject
public void setB(int b) {
   this.b = b
}
```

Another way is to use constructor injection like this:

```
public YourClass {
   private int a;
   private int b;

   @Inject
   public YourClass(int a, int b){
      this.a = a;
      this.b = b;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to test methods which using private parameters without
>   getters(Injected)?

Only with reflection as you don't have direct way to set these fields.
You can do this at hand or with tool such PowerMock.

The [`WhiteBox`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-reflect/1.6.4/org/powermock/reflect/Whitebox.html) class allows to achieve it.

Now, I don't advise this way.
It is tricky and dependencies of the component should be visible to make them clear and to also allow them to be naturally switchable and testable.

You are not forced to use setters.
You could use a constructor injection.

```
@Inject
public Foo(Int a, Int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

It is a little more verbose but it is really not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you meant is to use `@Inject` (from `javax.inject`), then you could use `@InjectMocks` from Mockito, though this probably won't work too well with primitive values (assuming you meant to write `int` rather than `Int`).

There are some caveats to using this, however: https://tedvinke.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mockito-why-you-should-not-use-injectmocks-annotation-to-autowire-fields/